# PHP e javascript - Pegando valor javascript em PHP (uso de session)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, post, get

No site que assumi de outro desenvolvedor, feito em PHP e Javascript, há uma busca de eventos criados (todos cadastrados em tabela de banco MySQL). Em cada evento buscado, criei um botão pra poder excluir o mesmo:

```
<input name="excluir" type="button" class="textDescricaoSobre font13" value="Excluir" onclick="excluiEvento(<?php echo $evento['id'];?>)" style="cursor: pointer; width: 55px; margin-left: 10px;" />
```

E a função de exclusão do evento, em javascript:

```
function excluiEvento(val){
    var valor = val;
    location.href = "http://meusite/excluir/"+valor;
}
```

Sendo que esse link vai pra função excluir, definida no meu arquivo de Controller:

```
public function excluir(){
    class_exists('Servico') || include_once CLASS_PATH . 'Servico.class.php';

    echo "<script>alert('Evento ".$_POST['valor']." foi pego')</script>";
    self::consultaeventos();
}
```

Tudo funciona bem, mas o valor da variável javascript *valor* não é exibido no alerta. Como eu posso fazer pra ver esse valor? Uso Session? Uso $_GET em vez de $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está acontecendo porque voce esta passando o valor na url como um diretório, reescreva a função javascript para:

```
function excluiEvento(val){
    var valor = val;
    location.href = "http://meusite/excluir/?valor="+valor;
}
```

adicionei **?valor=** na url

E o código php ao invés de $_POST['valor'] use $_GET['valor']